# Document created by Novacode docx is very big and seems not compressed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, docx

I have created a new document with [novacode docx](http://docx.codeplex.com).

Document consists of about 30 documents inserted into main document.

Each sub document is compressed and very small(about 10 KB);

Everything is OK except result document is very big (about 5 MB) .

It seems that it is not compressed at all.

I am using VS 2012 and Novacode DocX Version 1.0.0.12

any suggestions ?